# WatchKit Invalid Bundle Structure- WatchKitStub

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

Just wanted to share this answer. While submitting to the App Store I got an error saying the Bundle Structure including WatchKitStub was invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to navigate to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/(DateOfArchive)
Then clicked Show Package Contents of the archive
Then Products/Applications
Show Package Contents of the Application
Then I deleted the WatchKitStub folder

Comment: Sounds like a good solution but... did you discover the real reason?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not, only the nominal solution. Sorry! :/